# Swift 3 Alamofire invalid url error

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

When I made request using Alamofire I got invalid url error.My url contains ^ character and this is why I got error but when I paste same url on chrome it works.How can I use ^ character in my Alamofire request.

Comment: @EricAya Thank you.Works like a charm

Comment: You're welcome, Emre.